# Twitter log-in issue no phone to receive sms

Tags: twitter, verification

I no longer have access to the phone number I used for 2 step verification. I do not have a backup code either.

Answer (score 1):

As described on the [Twitter help pages](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/issues-with-login-authentication):

> **I lost my phone**
>
> - If you are no longer logged in to your account and do not have access to an active backup code, please [contact Support](https://help.twitter.com/forms) for assistance
>
> *Note: If you're still logged in to your account, you can remove your phone from your Mobile settings on twitter.com. Click Delete my phone and login verification will be automatically disabled for your account.*